Applying the linearity of $f$ in the proof of Proposition 1.5 in Brezis
This question references the proof that Brezis give that the hyperplane $H = [f = \alpha]$ is closed iff $f$ is continuous. Here, $f$ is a linear functional (not necessarily continuous) that does not vanish identically. The proof is shown in the post here for reference.
Following the proof, I denoted $t_{0} = \frac{f(x_{1}) - \alpha}{f(x_{1}) - f(x_{0})}$ and showed that $t_{0} \in (0, 1) \subset [0, 1]$. Since $f$ is linear, we have that:
$$f(x_{t_{0}}) = (1 - t_{0})f(x_{0}) + t_{0}f(x_{1})$$
$$=\left( 1 - \frac{f(x_{1}) - \alpha}{f(x_{1}) - f(x_{0})} \right)f(x_{0}) + \frac{f(x_{1}) - \alpha}{f(x_{1}) - f(x_{0})}f(x_{1})$$
$$= \frac{f(x_{1}) - f(x_{0}) - f(x_{1}) + \alpha}{f(x_{1}) - f(x_{0})}f(x_{0}) + \frac{f(x_{1}) - \alpha}{f(x_{1}) - f(x_{0})}f(x_{1})$$
$$= \frac{\alpha - f(x_{0})}{f(x_{1}) - f(x_{0})}f(x_{0}) + \frac{f(x_{1}) - \alpha}{f(x_{1}) - f(x_{0})}f(x_{1})$$
$$= \frac{\alpha\left( f(x_{0}) - f(x_{1}) \right) + \left( f(x_{1}) \right)^{2} - \left( f(x_{0}) \right)^{2}}{f(x_{1}) - f(x_{0})}$$
$$= \frac{-\alpha\left( f(x_{1}) - f(x_{0}) \right)}{f(x_{1}) - f(x_{0})} + \frac{\left( f(x_{1}) \right)^{2} - \left( f(x_{0}) \right)^{2}}{f(x_{1}) - f(x_{0})}$$
$$= -\alpha + \frac{\left( f(x_{1}) + f(x_{0}) \right)\left( f(x_{1}) - f(x_{0}) \right)}{f(x_{1}) - f(x_{0})}$$
$$= f(x_{0}) + f(x_{1}) - \alpha$$
However, the last expression does not look like it equates to $\alpha$. The issue seems to be that $f(x_{0})$ and $f(x_{1})$ are in the wrong place: if we were to replace $f(x_{0})$ with $f(x_{1})$ and $f(x_{1})$ with $f(x_{0})$ in the first line of the work above, then the resulting expression would equal $\alpha$. However, that is not the definition of $x_{t}$ that is being used in the book as the standard parameterization of the straight line segment starting at $x_{0}$ and terminating at $x_{1}$. I found some lecture notes online which instead use $t_{0} = \frac{\alpha - f(x_{0})}{f(x_{1}) - f(x_{0})}$, and this value of $t_{0}$ would result in $f(x_{t_{0}}) = \alpha$ by applying that value of $t_{0}$ to my work above, but the paper instead defines $x_{t} = tx_{0} + (1 - t)x_{1} \quad (t \in [0, 1])$, which is different to the definition I am using. I know I am making some trivial mistake since the Brezis proof should be correct, but I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. I don't need a proper answer to this question since this exercise is meant to be trivial: I would prefer comments on this post giving a hint or an explanation of why my thinking is wrong.

What you have shown in your work is correct. The choice of $t_{0} := \frac{f(x_{1})-\alpha }{f(x_{1})-f(x_{0}) }$ does not imply that $f(x_{t_{0}}) = \alpha$ and there are counterexamples under the conditions stated in the proof. However, as you said, if you take $t_{0} := \frac{\alpha -f(x_{0}) }{f(x_{1})-f(x_{0}) }$, then it is always the case that $f(x_{t_{0}}) = \alpha$. Another way to see this is that $f(x_{t_{0}}) = \alpha$ if and only if $\alpha = (1-t_{0})f(x_{0}) + t_{0}f(x_{1})$. Because $(1-t_{0})f(x_{0}) + t_{0}f(x_{1}) = f(x_{0}) + t_{0}(f(x_{1}) - f(x_{0}))$, subtracting both sides of the original equation by $f(x_{0})$ and then diving both sides by $f(x_{1}) - f(x_{0})$ obtains $t_{0} = \frac{\alpha -f(x_{0}) }{f(x_{1})-f(x_{0}) }$ as desired.
Note that $\frac{\alpha -f(x_{0}) }{f(x_{1})-f(x_{0}) } = 1 - \frac{f(x_{1})-\alpha }{f(x_{1})-f(x_{0}) }$, so it is most likely the case that some small detail was overlooked in Brezis' book.

Oh ok, thank you for the response! I also did what you did and set $\alpha = (1 - t_{0})f(x_{0}) + t_{0}f(x_{1})$ to derive that $t_{0} = \frac{\alpha - f(x_{0})}{f(x_{1}) - f(x_{0})}$, however, I did not include it in my post because I gaslighted myself into thinking I did something wrong since that was not what Brezis said! What do you mean by "there are counterexamples..." though? Do you mean that you can define $f$ such that $f(x_{0}) + f(x_{1}) - \alpha \neq \alpha$? If so, that is clear since the $t_{0}$ given in the Brezis proof does not yield $f(x_{t_{0}}) = \alpha$.

No problem! If $f(x_{0}) + f(x_{1}) = 2\alpha$, then the $t_{0}$ defined as in Brezis' proof does yield $f(x_{t_{0}}) = \alpha$ because $f(x_{0}) + f(x_{1}) - \alpha = \alpha$. But if $f(x_{0}) + f(x_{1}) \neq 2\alpha$, which can be obtained by adjusting the value of $\alpha$ if necessary, then $f(x_{t_{0}}) \neq \alpha$. That is what I was referring to by the existence of counterexamples.
